# "Independent" Variables in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

I am trying to plot the solutions to the Kepler problem. I am using Manipulate. It plots the orbits, the equipotential lines and the position of the planet. When I move the time variable, only the position of the planet changes, but mathematica seems to recalculate the equipotential lines and the orbits. What should I change?

```
\[Epsilon] = 
  2^10 $MachineEpsilon; (*Added \[Epsilon] to the denominator to \
avoid division by 0*) 
vars = {q[t], p[t]}; 
range = 1.5;  (*Range of the plots*)

pVector[{q_, p_}] := 
 Arrow@{q, 
   q + .5 p} (*The arrow showing the momentum should be scaled by a \
0.5 factor*)

keplerEqs[q0_, 
   p0_] = {{Derivative[1][q][t] == p[t], 
    Derivative[1][p][t] == -(q[t]/(Norm[q[t]]^3 + \[Epsilon]))}, {q[
      0] == q0, p[0] == p0}};
V[q_] := -1/(Norm@q + \[Epsilon]) (*Kepler's potential*)

keplerSol[q0_, p0_, tmax_] := 
  keplerSol[q0, p0] = 
   First@NDSolve[keplerEqs[q0, p0], vars, {t, -tmax, tmax}];

Manipulate[
 Q = Evaluate[q[t] /. keplerSol[q0, p0, tmax]];
 P = Evaluate[p[t] /. keplerSol[q0, p0, tmax]];

 show = {showPotential, showOrbit, showP0, showQ, 
   showP}; (*Things that should be shown in the graph*)

 plots = {potentialPlot, orbitPlot, P0Plot, QPlot, PPlot};

 potentialPlot = 
  ContourPlot[V[{x, y}], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None];
 orbitPlot = ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Q,
   {t, -tmax, tmax}
   ];
 P0Plot = Graphics@pVector[{q0, p0}];
 QPlot = Graphics@{PointSize[0.05], Point[Evaluate@(Q /. t -> T)]};
 PPlot = Graphics@pVector[{Q, P} /. t -> T];

 Show[Pick[plots, show], PlotRange -> range, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  Axes -> True],

 (*Controls*)
 {{q0, {0.1, 1}}, Locator},
 {{q0, {0.1, 1}, "r0"}},
 {{p0, {1, .1}, "p0"}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 {{p0, {1, .1}, ""}}, Delimiter,
 {{T, 0, "t"}, -tmax, tmax, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tmax, 10, "tmax"}, 1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{showOrbit, True, "Orbit"}, Checkbox, ControlPlacement -> Right},
 {{showPotential, False, "Potential"}, Checkbox, 
  ControlPlacement -> Right},
 {{showP0, True, "p0"}, Checkbox, ControlPlacement -> Right},
 {{showQ, False, "q(t)"}, Checkbox, ControlPlacement -> Right},
 {{showP, False, "p(t)"}, Checkbox, ControlPlacement -> Right}
 ]
```

UPDATE: I CHANGED THE CODE TO MAKE IT MORE READABLE, HOWEVER, THE SPACING IS NOT CONSERVED WHEN YOU COPY IT. THE ORIGINAL FILE IS [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1012958/Kepler.nb)

Comment: if you make your code readable, may be you'll get better help. I can't even read the code. This is how it looks on my notebook ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/idjyR.png) may be it will help if you start by removing all the subscript boxes stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I did this very quickly. I'll rewrite it and update the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no Manipulate master, but from previous nasty experiences, I have a few tips:

Read the related tutorials, not only the direct documentation. They explain a great deal of the internal "mechanics", and have some examples that make for some great A-ha moments.
    - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html
    - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html
    - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html

Regarding your code, you should aim to **"produce dynamic content"**, not **"produce content dynamically"**. In other words, you should use `Dynamic` surgically. Compare these:

```
Dynamic[Point[{x,y}]] (* Dynamically creates a new point for each new {x,y} coordinates *)

Point[Dynamic[{x,y}]] (* Creates a single point with coordinates {x,y} that dynamically change *)
```

The second `Point` uses less resources than the first, and is what you should aim for.

With that in mind, take a look at your code: a single `Dynamic` (that is created by `Manipulate`, as explained in the docs) wraps all your code and recalculates everything at every parameter change. If you help `Manipulate` by giving hints, through nested `Dynamic`s, of what changes when, and also dived things hierarchically, you can achieve better performance

This changes whenever `q0`,  `p0` or `tmax`, changes.

```
Q = Evaluate[q[t] /. keplerSol[q0, p0, tmax]];
P = Evaluate[p[t] /. keplerSol[q0, p0, tmax]];
plotA = {ContourPlot[
    V[{x, y}], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
    ContourShading -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
   ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Q, {t, -tmax, tmax}], 
   Graphics@pVector[{q0, p0}]};
```

But this only changes when T changes:

```
 plotB = {Graphics@{PointSize[0.05], 
          Point[Evaluate@(Q /. t -> T)]}, 
          Graphics@pVector[{Q, P} /. t -> T]};
```

And this, only when the `showXXX` parameters change:

```
 Show[Pick[ plotA ~Join~ plotB, {showPotential, showOrbit, showP0, showQ, 
      showP}], PlotRange -> 1.5, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> True]
```

Combining it all and adding some `Dynamic`s on the smallest parts I could manage, the core of your `Manipulate` becomes

```
Q = Evaluate[q[t] /. keplerSol[q0, p0, tmax]];
P = Evaluate[p[t] /. keplerSol[q0, p0, tmax]];
plotA = {ContourPlot[
   V[{x, y}], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   ContourShading -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Q, {t, -tmax, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MaxRecursion -> 5], Graphics@pVector[{q0, p0}]};
plotB = {Graphics@{PointSize[0.05], 
    Dynamic@Point[Evaluate@(Q /. t -> T)]}, 
  Graphics@Dynamic@pVector[{Q, P} /. t -> T]};
Dynamic[
 Show[Pick[
   plotA~Join~plotB, {showPotential, showOrbit, showP0, showQ, 
    showP}], PlotRange -> 1.5, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> True]
 , TrackedSymbols :> {showPotential, showOrbit, showP0, showQ, showP}
 ]
```

Here's a comparison, with you version on the right:

[image: Manipulate comparison]